# Select distinct and random rows from one table that match a value from another table

Tags: php, mysql, left-join, distinct, outer-join

This topic has been much discussed but I was unable to find a solution that I can modify and make it work for my case. So maybe a more advanced expert will be able to help out.

I have a table called `keywords` which contains about 3000 rows with distinct keywords. Against each keyword there is a matching `product_id`, which are NOT unique, i.e. some of them are repeated. Table looks something like this:

```
+---------+------------+
| keyword | product_id |
+---------+------------+
| apple1  | 15         |
| apple2  | 15         |
| pear    | 205        |
| cherry  | 307        |
| melon   | 5023       |
+---------+------------+
```

I have a second table called `inventory` that contains about 500K of products each with it's own product ID and other product data.

Now I need to get one random product row from `inventory` table that matches each `product_id` from `keywords` table and insert those rows into another table.

Resulting table should be something like this:

```
+---------+------------+---------+---------+---------+
| keyword | product_id | product |  data1  |  data2  |
+---------+------------+---------+---------+---------+
| apple1  | 15         | app5    |  d1     |  d2     |
| apple2  | 15         | app1    |  d1     |  d2     |
| pear    | 205        | pear53  |  d1     |  d2     |
| cherry  | 307        | cher74  |  d1     |  d2     |
| melon   | 5023       | melo2   |  d1     |  d2     |
+---------+------------+---------+---------+---------+
```

This is my query at the moment and the problem is how to get a random product from `inventory` that matches a `product_id`:

```
SELECT keywords.keyword, keywords.product_id, inventory.*
FROM keywords LEFT OUTER JOIN
     inventory
     ON keywords.product_id = inventory.id            
ORDER BY RAND();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want it to only return rows when there is a match between the tables, then you want a regular (i.e. inner) `join` not a `left outer join`.  You can also add the word `distinct`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT keywords.keyword, keywords.product_id, inventory.*
FROM keywords JOIN
     inventory
     ON keywords.product_id = inventory.id            
ORDER BY RAND();
```

And if you only want 1 row returned, add `limit 1` at the end.

```
SELECT keywords.keyword, keywords.product_id, inventory.*
FROM keywords JOIN
     inventory
     ON keywords.product_id = inventory.id            
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Hi developerwjk, thank you for the answer. I actually want to have a random match for every `keyword` and the result to return only unique `keyword`s. Now i get duplicate keywords for every product that matches the `product_id`

Comment: @BradG, You'll have to add some grouping with `group by` probably. Group by the criteria that you want the values to be unique for. (FYI, Add the `group by` clause before the `order by` clause.)

Comment: this works, just tried with `left outer join` and `group by` and all is fine. One more question, how can I limit the keywords to select, i.e. add something like `WHERE keywords.type = '2'`. Maybe nested select?

Comment: @BradG,  You can include a `where` clause. There no need to nest.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT keywords.keyword, keywords.product_id, inventory.*
  FROM keywords JOIN
   inventory
   ON keywords.product_id = inventory.id            
  ORDER BY RAND()
) tmp
GROUP BY tmp.keyword;
```

I also test it at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e559a9/2/0. Just run some times, the result will be randomize.

Comment: Hi Truong Hua, thank you for the answer! I cannot get this to work properly, it overloads the MySQL server when tried to execute it.

Comment: Really? can you show me your table structures? However, I think that you need to limit your result because I don't think you need to get all from your keywords table. Furthermore, order by RAND() is not good for performance, but it depend on your table size too.